# Where to put licence notes of used artifacts

Tags: placement

I intend to use an icon in a website, of which the licence requires a link back to the designers site.

What is a good place to put this link into?

My current idea is to have a link in the footer to a separate licence page and list there the licence of the page itself a long with a list of all the things that come with their own licence.

Note: I put this question in UX, because the question is mainly about how to place this information so that: It is discoverable enough to satisfy the original creators, but also doesn't limit usability for the normal user who doesn't care about the legal stuff involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a 'credits' page with a link in the footer. This 'credits' page could include your team, the software you have used and any other license details pertinent to that.

This could be a page that you can refer to in future, i.e. in your next job, showing your work is your work. Such a page may be 'no follow, no index' so that it does not show up on search engines.

If the site is really good and other companies want a site like yours then it could get you the work in.